# Deserialize JSON of an unknown type (Google Map API)

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I'm trying to work with the google maps api.  This URL is EXACTLY what I need:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77379

Take a look at the results.  It has all the info I need... lat, lon, state, country.  Trouble is, I don't know how to extract this data.  I tried this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77379");
object myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

While that doesn't error out, `myObject` doesn't end up being anything useful.  (Or, maybe it is and I just don't know it?)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to create objects to extract the json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your class structure

```
public class AddressComponent
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast2 northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest2 southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> postcode_localities { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

And you have to do

```
RootObject rootObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(content);
```

Try referring to this stackoverflow posting if you would prefer other ways
[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks!  I already had the classes, but I was trying to deserialize to Results and not to RootObject.

Comment: sometimes we overlook small things. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience using JSON I have always used this method:

```
object myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

Would that work?  Or is this something different from what you're doing?

Comment: It doesn't appear that OP is using JSON.NET.

Comment: yeah, I am.  Sorry - my OP is using a wrapper around JSON.NET.  I'll try this.